# Ordering positions of a tile on a board using C

Tags: c

Suppose I have Black ('B') and White ('W') tiles on a board of n x n dimension. n is a user input, which can go from 'a' to 'z'. When user entered n, it will print the "board" with 2 Whites and 2 Blacks in the center. Then a number of steps will be entered by the user. Assume n is always even, and user input will only be stopped from storing when '!!!' is entered. So the tiles take the position I need to print out the configuration of the board after a series of user input as follows:

```
Enter a board configuration:
Bbd
Bad
Wde
Wcb
!!!
```

Then, it SHOULD print:

```
  abcdef 
a UUUBUU
b UUUBUU
c UWWBUU
d UUBWWU
e UUUUUU
f UUUUUU
```

However, I realized that unless I re-order the tiles by increasing order, so from the previous example:

```
Enter a board configuration:
Bad
Bbd
Wcb
Wde
!!!
```

It would only print out one or a couple, but not all of the tiles. 
It applies to tiles with same row number but different column number, or vice versa:

```
Enter a board configuration:
 Baa
 Bab
 Wbc
 Wbd
 !!!
```

would work, but

```
Enter a board configuration:
 Bab
 Baa
 Wbd
 Wbc
 !!!
```

wouldn't.

There is no upper limit of how many moves in total there are (well, the absolute maximum is the size of the board so 26*26 - 4, but I feel that is too inefficient), only that it stops once "!!!" is read.

How can I write a function to order these tiles by row and column?

Thank you!

The following is my code for this part (it's actually a helper function, but I wrote it in another file in main() so that it's easier to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int sizeBoard = 6;

    int i, j; //row and col, a is the number of moves - 1
    int numMove = 0; 
    char color[numMove], row[numMove], col[numMove];
    char board[sizeBoard][sizeBoard];

    printf("Enter board configuration: \n");
    scanf(" %c%c%c", &color[numMove], &row[numMove], &col[numMove]); 
        //color[a] = board[row + 1][col + 2];

    while ((color[numMove] != '!') && (row[numMove] != '!') && (col[numMove] != '!')) {
        numMove++;
        scanf(" %c%c%c", &color[numMove], &row[numMove], &col[numMove]); 
    }

    printf("  "); //two spaces before the column header (row 0)
    for (j = 2; j < sizeBoard + 2; j++) {
        board[0][j] = 'a' - 2 + j;
        printf("%c", board[0][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    numMove = 0; //set it back to initial value that gives first input of color[], row[] and col[]
    for (i = 1; i < sizeBoard + 1; i++) {
        board[i][0] = 'a' - 1 + i;
        printf("%c ", board[i][0]); 
        for (j = 2; j < sizeBoard + 2; j++) {

            //initial placement of the tiles in center
            if (((j == ((sizeBoard + 2) / 2)) && (i == ((sizeBoard + 1) / 2))) || ((j == ((sizeBoard + 2) / 2) + 1) && (i == ((sizeBoard + 1) / 2) + 1)))
                board[i][j] = 'W';
            else if (((j == ((sizeBoard + 2) / 2) + 1) && (i == ((sizeBoard + 1) / 2))) || ((j == ((sizeBoard + 2) / 2)) && (i == ((sizeBoard + 1) / 2) + 1)))
                board[i][j] = 'B';
            else  
                board[i][j] = 'U'; //if not centered, set it as unoccupied

            //mid-game placement of tiles
            if ((i == ((row[numMove] - 'a') + 1)) && (j == ((col[numMove] - 'a') + 2))) {
                board[i][j] = color[numMove];
                numMove++;
            }
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the initial input print (assuming input like "Bad" corresponds to placing `value B` at `row a` and `column d` is :
 abcdef 
a UUUBUU
b UUUBUU
c UWUUUU
d UUUUWU
e UUUUUU
f UUUUUU

Or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Oh yes, this question is actually the second step of a project. The very first thing should be to print a WBBW in the center, and afterwards it prompts for inputs of some number of steps and print again. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Maximum size
#define Maximum_size 26
// board initial size
#define Ini_Row_size 6
#define Ini_Col_size 6
/* test input
Bbd
Bad
Wde
Wcb
!!!
*/
int main(void) {
    // Maximum size
    int sizeMax = Maximum_size;
    // board size
    int sizeRow = Ini_Row_size - 1;
    int sizeCol = Ini_Row_size - 1;

    int i, j;
    char color, row, col;
    char board[sizeMax][sizeMax];
    // board initial
    for ( i=0 ; i<sizeMax ; i++ ) for ( j=0 ; j<sizeMax ; j++ ) board[i][j] = 'U';

    printf("Enter board configuration: \n");

    // moves
    while (true) {

        // read the moves
        scanf(" %c%c%c", &color, &row, &col); 
        if( (color == '!') && (row == '!') && (col == '!') ) break;

        // turn char to int (index)
        int temp_row = row - 'a';
        int temp_col = col - 'a';

        // if the move is out-of the sizeMax then ignore the move
        if( temp_row>=sizeMax || temp_row<0 || temp_col>=sizeMax || temp_col<0) continue;

        // save the color
        board[temp_row][temp_col] = color;

        // update the board size when the move is out-of the board range
        sizeRow = sizeRow > temp_row ? sizeRow : temp_row;
        sizeCol = sizeCol > temp_col ? sizeCol : temp_col;
    }

    // the size have to +1 because for-loop is i<size
    sizeRow++;
    sizeCol++;

    // set the center
        // center index
    int ci[4][2]={  {(sizeRow-1)/2,(sizeCol-1)/2},
                    {(sizeRow)/2,(sizeCol)/2},
                    {(sizeRow-1)/2,(sizeCol)/2},
                    {(sizeRow)/2,(sizeCol-1)/2} };
        // center color
    char cc[4]={ 'W', 'W', 'B', 'B'};

    for( i=0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
        // if there is no any move to center point then set center color
        if( board[ (ci[i][0]) ][ (ci[i][1]) ] == 'U')
            board[ (ci[i][0]) ][ (ci[i][1]) ] = cc[i];
    }

    // show the board

    // first row
    printf("  ");
    for ( i=0 ; i<sizeCol ; i++ ) printf("%c", 'a'+i );
    printf("\n");

    // first col & board
    for ( i=0 ; i<sizeRow ; i++ ) {
        // first col
        printf("%c ", 'a'+i);
        for ( j=0 ; j<sizeCol ; j++ ) {
            // board
            printf("%c", board[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a game?
If so, I think it should change the way to operate.
Now is like:

```
-- user input
move-1
move-2
move-3
...
-- board output
board
```

Maybe change to this way:

```
-- user input
move-1
-- board output
board
-- user input
move-2
-- board output
board
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!